# How to achieve redirection in a c shell?

Tags: c, shell, sorting, redirect, dup

How do i use dup (or dup2) to achieve redirection, in other words to execute commands like `sort < in.txt > out.txt`. *System calls that create a new shell like (bin/sh/) are not allowed.

Comment: you're trying to WRITE a c shell, or use a C shell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [redirecting I/O, implementation of a shell in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846272/redirecting-i-o-implementation-of-a-shell-in-c)

Comment: @MarcB i'm trying to write a c shell...